# iphone alpha numeric ascending

Tags: sqlite

Can you help me to get sqlite query for alpha numeric ascending?
Condition: alphanumeric values should come in first and character should be in second

**Result format is given below**

Eg: 1.apple
    2.Orange
    8.Banana
    15.Mango
    Animals
    Vegetables

1.apple, 2.Orange, 8.Banana, 15.Mango ---Alpha numeric
Animals, Vegetables ---char

Comment: Please clarify your question. It is not clear what you wish to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

Its called ORDER BY in SQL syntax. Its simple:
`SELECT my_attr FROM my_table ORDER BY my_attr`

For more info check: http://www.sqlite.org/docs.html

Comment: Thanks Majster.I have used your suggestion.But I am getting the result like  1.apple, 15.Mango, 2.Orange, 8.Banana, Animals Vegetables.Here "15.Mango" is coming under "1.apple" but it should be come below

Comment: How do you want to sort it? Do you have numbers there or not? `ORDER BY` is case sensitive. You can solve it by using a function `ORDER BY lower(my_attr)`.